# "Escape" Bind Variable ? in JDBC SQL search

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, escaping, bind-variables

So I am coding in Java, using JDBC with SQL to get data from a database. I cannot chnage the data or the column names in the database. Everything worked perfectly until I was told today that another column of the database was needed.

So I tried to add the column name to the select statement, however I get an error:

**"java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2."**

Here is the variable and name for the column: String est = "\"Estimates Complete?\"";

So after LOTS of research, it seems that there is something called "Bind Variables" in JDBC and ? happens to be one of them. I keep finding forum posts and answers on how to create Bind Variables, but nothing on how to "Escape" them. I cannot change the value of the Estimates Complete? column, and it is needed for my program.

If I try String est = "Estimates Complete?";, then the error I get is:

**java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]COUNT field incorrect**

Anyone know if it is possible? Thanks.

Edit: Code example:

```
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
String tableName = "\"Open WRs V2\"", data1 = "\"Project Name\"",est = "Estimates Complete?";
String selTable = "SELECT " + data1  + "," + est+ " FROM " + tableName;
s.execute(selTable);
ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
while ((rs.next())) {
    String name = (rs.getString(1));
    String estimate= rs.getString(2);
    System.out.println("test: "+estmate);
}
s.close();
```

Comment: Have you tried using brackets `[]`?

Comment: Could you show an example of your SQL?

Comment: I added code. Forgive how badly formatted it looks. I still haven't completed figured out this site.

Comment: @Luiggi, I'm not sure what you mean by adding brackets, but I tried: String est = "\"Estimates Complete[?]\""; and it gave: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in query expression '[Estimates Complete[Pa_RaM000]]'. Then I tried String est = "\"[Estimates Complete?]\""; and it gave: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in query expression '[[Estimates CompletePa_RaM000]]'.

Answer (score 0):

can you replace the ? with chr(63) like in the answer here :

[How to avoid ODBC parameterization for the question mark character ? within literals and comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348932/how-to-avoid-odbc-parameterization-for-the-question-mark-character-within-lite)